# Evaluating $\iiint_{\Omega} z\ \max(\sqrt{3} x, y)\ dx dy dz$, where $\Omega=\{(x,y,z) : x\geq 0, 0\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}, 0\leq z\leq x+y \}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm struggling with an integral, I've tried but I get a long thing and I don't think it should be so long.

$\Omega=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} : x\geq 0, 0\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}, 0\leq z\leq x+y \}$

$$\iiint_{\Omega} z\ \max(\sqrt{3} x, y)\ dx dy dz$$

I would divide $\Omega$ in two pieces and then try to calculate the integrals but it becomes quite long, is it the right way? Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like the right approach to me.  Impossible to say if you've carried it out correctly without seeing your calculations.

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: You should include the work you've done so that people don't waste time (theirs or yours) duplicating your effort or telling you things you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The $xy$ domain is a quarter of a circle and the locus where the $\max$ switches from one argument to the other has the equation $\sqrt3 x=y$, i.e. a line from the origin with slope $\tan\dfrac\pi3$.

Hence in cylindrical coordinates, you distinguish two circular sectors:

$$I=\sqrt3\int_{r=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/3}\int_{z=0}^{x+y}zx\,dx\,dy\,dz+\int_{r=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_{z=0}^{x+y}zy\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

where $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$.

This simplifies to

$$I=\frac{\sqrt3}2\int_{r=0}^{1}r^4\,dr\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/3}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2\cos\theta\,d\theta+\frac12\int_{r=0}^{1}r^4\,dr\int_{\theta=\pi/3}^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2\sin\theta\,d\theta.$$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: where ?